# select an element based off a select value

Tags: javascript, html, css, function, element

I am trying to take the value of a select element and match it to a dataset of another element to affect a transition on that element.

So I have two tags with data in them:

```
<select data-name="name goes here" updateElement()></select>

<select value="what ever option is picked" applyTransition()></select>
```

When ever you change the option of data-name it will update a variable that holds the element I am trying to apply the transition affect on.

The goal is when you change the select with the `data-name` it updates and element the other select applies a transition too.

I haven't shared any of the actual code because it is a lot and would like to just share what is needed.

Comment: I understand if this can be confusing to answer. But essentially when a change is detected on one select it runs a function to update which element will be affected by the other select's change.

Answer (score 0):

Okay so I figured this out after banging my head against the console.

```
const yourElements = document.querySelectorAll(".your-class-name");
let selectedElement;
```

So if your elements have a `data-property` set you can "pluck" that one out.

```
for(let i = 0; i < yourElements.length; i++){
if(select.value === your-class-name[i].dataset.property){
selectedElement = document.querySelector(`[data-property= 
${locationHands[i].dataset.property}]`);}
```

Then you should be able to see `selectedElement` as the element you want.

You can then use that variable where ever.

If you know of a better or more efficient way to achieve this, please let me know.

Comment: Are you looking for "Attribute selectors"? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors